# Flex: How to avoid flickering cursor for custom cursor on mouse down

Tags: apache-flex

I set a custom cursor using the `CursorManager` on a sprite's mouse down event.

The custom cursor is shown. However, when I keep the mouse pressed the system cursor shows as well and is flickering.

Any idea how to prevent this?

I've tried:
- higher cursor priorities
- preventing the default in the mouse down event

nothing seems to work.

Changing the cursor just on mouse over works fine.

Thanks
Stefan

PS:
- Safari on Mac
- Flash debug player 10.0.2.54

Comment: It seems to happen when other websites are open that (I guess) request data in the background. I see it with gmail and youTube and others, but e.g. not with google.com:

The cursor flickers when gmail is open and it stops flickering immediately when I close gmail.

Any ideas?